# Contacts related to the account are transferred to the new owner automatically

Tags: process-builder

When did this become default functionality in SF? I had to create process builder steps on both Contact and Account years ago to sync the contact owner to the Account owner. Now all of a sudden, there is documentation saying that this is default functionality, yet I can't see anywhere in release notes when it was made available?

See here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_owner_transfer.htm&type=5

"Contacts related to the account are transferred to the new owner automatically."

Now I have a business requirement to DISABLE this default functionality. There are so many Idea threads asking for it, and understandably they are not delivered, because you could solve it so eaily with process builder, but the "new" default behaviour is terrible! If I update an account owner, it cascades down to all contacts and updates the system LastModifiedDate field, but it does NOT cause process builder to execute off this change. I've seen threads saying that you need to write a trigger to restore the ownership, but I am not prepared to solve it this way unless I absolutely have to.

Can anyone at all shed any light on this?